# How can I add a listView column header a click event programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a dynamic listview and I am trying to achieve the same thing as in the picture bellow.

[image]

How can I do that programmatically. I have tried:
 [image]

Comment: Images to show code. I'm speechless...

Comment: Please do not screen-cap code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this:

```
listView.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Header_Click));
```

Comment: When I add the following method:

Comment: public void Header_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){ }

Comment: It's a `RoutedEventHandler`, so the args have to be `RoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: You do create a `RoutedEventHandler` in the `AddHandler` method, right? Compare your code again, it has to work, i tested it.

Comment: Sorry about that I am new to wpf and I initialized the event before adding the gridview to the listview. I added that event by placing a button then adding that event handler with the button. It even gives me a problem when I place it on the loaded event. Maybe I have to use a sleep function then add it. Anyways thanks a lot! Sorry for taking so long